# Android Room Database Data is not getting inserted?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack, android-paging

I am inserting data into room database receiving from network.
It doesn't show any errors and neither the app is crashing but the screen is empty and table is empty
All works fine but when i use Stetho Debug Tool and look into **feed table** nothing is inserted ,Can anyone figure it out and help me. And also to see whether the PageListAdapter and LivePageListBuilder is correctly implemented or Not?

1.**Room DB Data is not insrted**
2.**Paging Implementation**

This is the Dao Method

```
//Post feed item
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun insert(feed:feed)
```

Repository class:

```
class FeedRepository (
    private val feedDao: FeedDao
){


private var lastRequestedItem = 0
private var isRequestInProgress = false
var executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
companion object {
    lateinit var feedList:List<Feed>
    private const val DEFAULT_NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE = 50
    private const val DEAULT_DATABASE_PAGE_SIZE = 20
    private val apiClient = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(UserClient::class.java)
    // For Singleton instantiation
    @Volatile private var instance: FeedRepository? = null

    fun getInstance(feedDao: FeedDao) =
            instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: FeedRepository(feedDao).also { instance = it }
            }
}


fun showFeed():LiveData<PagedList<feed>>{
    Timber.d("showFeed() method called")
    val dataSourceFactory = feedDao.getAllFeed()
    val boundaryCallback = FeedBoundaryCallBack(id = lastRequestedItem)
    val builder = LivePagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory, DEAULT_DATABASE_PAGE_SIZE)
            .setBoundaryCallback(boundaryCallback)
            .build()
    return builder

}

public fun getFeedResponse() {
    Timber.i("getFeedResponse()")
    if(isRequestInProgress) return
    isRequestInProgress = true
    val call: Call<FeedResult> = apiClient.getFeed(DEFAULT_NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE,lastRequestedItem)
    call.enqueue(object :Callback<FeedResult>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<FeedResult>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Timber.d(t.toString())
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<FeedResult>?, response: Response<FeedResult>?) {
            if(response!!.isSuccessful){
                //lastRequestedItem += response?.body()!!.size
                feedList = response?.body()!!.feedList
                for (i in feedList){
                    var name = i.username
                    var media = i.mUrl
                    var loc = i.location
                    var like = i.likesCount.toString()
                    var timeStamp = i.timeStamp
                    var id = i.id.toLong()
                    var res:feed = feed(id,name,media,timeStamp,loc,like)
                    addResponseTODB(res)
                }
                Timber.i("Successful Response -> Adding to DB")
                isRequestInProgress = false
            }else{
                when(response.code()){
                    400 -> Timber.d("Not Found 400")
                    500 -> Timber.d("Not logged in or Server broken")
                }

            }

        }
    })
}

private fun addResponseTODB(items:feed) ={
    executor.execute( {feedDao.insert(items)})
    Timber.d("Feed object Inserted into Database")
}
```

Adapter and ViewHolder:

```
class FeedAdapter : PagedListAdapter<feed,FeedAdapter.ViewHolder> 
   (FeedDiffCallBack()){
  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
  ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.feedrow,parent,false)
    )
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val feedItem = getItem(position)
    if(feedItem != null){
        holder.bind(feedItem)
    }
}

class ViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    //Retrieve data
    private val username:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username_txt)
    private val userPic:ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.feedImage)
    private val location:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postLocation)
    private val time:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postTime)
    private val post:ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postImage)

    fun bind(feed: feed) = with(itemView){
        //TODO:Bind Data with View
        if(feed == null) {
            post.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        else{
            showFeedData(feed)
        }

    }

    private fun showFeedData(feed: feed) {
        username.text = feed.username
        userPic.setImageURI(null)
        userPic.visibility = View.GONE
        location.text = feed.location
        time.text = feed.timeStamp.toString()
        post.setImageURI(Uri.parse(feed.mUrl))

    }

}

}

class FeedDiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<feed>() {
override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem:feed, newItem: feed): Boolean {
    return oldItem?.id == newItem?.id
}

override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: feed, newItem: feed): Boolean {
    return oldItem == newItem
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this in the answer section, because it's too much for the comment section.

> First, confirm whether the issue is in **Inserting** or in **showing in UI**.

1. Stetho Debug Tool doesn't work sometime, especially when ROOM is in WAL mode. So run your app in Emulator, then use the "Device Manager" and extract the DB, and see if the entries are inserted. If you are using Room in WAL mode, then you will notice a couple of files in addition to the DB. You need to extract that as well, to see the full DB.
2. If Insert is your problem, then you need to focus on that. Following are some places to look for:

   1. Check if `insert` method is called.
   2. Check if `insert` method is called with a proper feed
   3. Check if `insert` method is called from a non-ui thread

> Second, confirm if Adaper and ViewHolder is proper.

3. You can confirm that your Adapter and ViewHolder is working perfectly, by just pulling the DB from emulator and then populating it with some sample data and pushing the DB back to the emulator.

Comment: I've done it ,The data is getting inserted and i can now observe the DB table in Stetho debugger,But the problem is my  fragment ui doesn't work,It is neither showing up in preview mode nor in the emulator.